# Function $f:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ is differentiable if partial derivatives are continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ be a function from the euclidean space to a Hilbert space. Is it true that if the partial derivatives are continuous, then $f$ is differentiable? (the partial derivatives are defined in the analogous manner: $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+he_i)-f(x)}{h}$).

I tried to repeat the proof of the euclidean case, but it uses the mean value theorem. Maybe we could use the mean value inequality, since its proof uses the inner product, but I wasn't able to pinpoint how to use it exactly...

Comment: Even better, the function $f$ is continuously differentiable (i.e. the map $\mathbb{R}^k\to L(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{H}),\,x\mapsto Df(x)$ is contnuous w.r.t. the operator norm) if and only if the partial derivatives are continuous. You can even replace the Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$ by an arbitrary Banach space. A proof can be found in Amann, Escher: Analysis II (right now, I am to lazy to reproduce it here).

Comment: @MaoWao I imagined that if this was true, that would be the case (to mimic the euclidean : ) ). I'll take a look at the book, thank you very much.

Comment: There is also a proof in Dieudonné I just in case you don't have access to the book I mentioned above.

Comment: Another proof can be found in Cartan's book "Differential calculus" (also available in other languages). There, even the case $f : E_1 \times \ldots \times E_k \to \mathbb{H}$ is considered, where $E_i$ are Banach spaces.